# Windows Phone sends more than one web requests in order in a call

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8

Reccently, I am working on a project in Windows Phone. and In this project, to validate a user, I need to check at 3 web API, the logic is like below:
 Step 1: access web api 1 to get the token
 Step 2: access  web api 2 to get the username/password by the token retrieved in Step 1
 Step 3: access web API 3 to validate the user name/password in step 2

you can see we need to access those 3 API in order. as well know, window phone now access the network asynchronously, which causes a big challenge on make those API access in order, and which make the soure code hard to maintainace.

I also consider the synchronous source code like below, but I found there are some problems to access the network,many exeption will be thrown. For example, when an exception is thrown, I try to use asynchronous web request to access the same URL, it is OK. I am strugglig in it now. And I have to introduce thread to call it to avoid to block the UI thread.

internal static class HttpWebRequestExtensions
    {
        public const int DefaultRequestTimeout = 60000;

```
    public static bool IsHttpExceptionFound = false;

    public static WebResponse GetResponse(this WebRequest request, int nTimeOut = DefaultRequestTimeout)
    {
        var dataReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        var callback = new AsyncCallback(delegate(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                dataReady.Set();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                IsHttpExceptionFound = true;

            }
        });

        request.BeginGetResponse(callback, request);
        if (dataReady.WaitOne(nTimeOut))
        {
            return response;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static WebResponse PostRequest(this HttpWebRequest request, String postData, int nTimeOut = DefaultRequestTimeout)
    {
        var dataReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        var callback = new AsyncCallback(delegate(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);    //End the operation.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);                    //Convert the string into a byte array.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);                        //Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Close();
            dataReady.Set();
        });
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(callback, request);
        if (dataReady.WaitOne(nTimeOut))
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(nTimeOut);
            if (IsHttpExceptionFound)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException("Failed to get http response");
            } 
            return response;
        }
        return null;  
    }

}
```

Any suggestion on using asynchronous web request to solve my case?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example here of using asynchronous web services in a chained manner to call the Microsoft Translator service on WP7

Maybe it will give you some pointers?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/wp7translate.aspx

Comment: Thank, but after checking the article, it looks that I can't get much useful information on my question.